# How to find CPU utilazetion of mysql RDS instance

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds

How to find which process/query consume CPU in amazon mysql RDS instance? I have medium instance on amazon RDS of mysql, and It is working smoothly previously, but since yesterday Its throwing error 'connection timeout' while accessing RDS instance. When I checked cloud watch, It shows me high CPU utilization during that period. Now I want to check what is the problem? So, can some one tell me how to check it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

use '`show processlist`' in mysql. with this you can see which queries are in what state, doing what, since when

also check slow query log:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: But this happens in my live website in the mid-night. So, how can I check it manually? It there another way? thanks for reply.

Comment: write a script to save the output ran every minute. alternatively, check the added link above.

Answer (score 1):

Using show process list, you can see only current running thread info, but as per context of your query, you want to see the historical status. You can achieve it via enabling the slow query log and setting long query time to 1 second. You can pass slow query logs to cloud watch and can set alerts according to your db system loads and types of queries.